# Looping through array in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($top_name); $i++)
{
  for($i=0; $i<sizeof($top_name); $i++)
  {
    echo "<tr><td>".$sub_name[$i]."</td><td>".$sub_diff[$i]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$top_name[$i]."</td><td>".$top_diff[$i]."</td>  <td>".$top_size[$i]."</td></tr>";
  }
}

?>
```

Error :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TRY\data.php on line 28
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TRY\data.php on line 28

I'm trying to fetch arrays and arranging them in table but it is giving that error.

Please solve this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: $top_name is your array name ..??

Comment: You have a double `for` loop with same incrementing variable (`$i`): this don't make sense with your code. I think you can use only one loop. But what you want achieve?

Comment: Or maybe you have to change second loop with `$i<sizeof($sub_name)`, but also in this case, you have the change one of the incrementing variables, otherwise, in the second main loop, the `$i` value is that set by last deeper loop.

Comment: Consider `for($i=0, $num_items = sizeof($array); $i < $num_items; $i++) {` so the loop isn't counting the array items on every iteration.  Or use foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have these elements in `$top_name` and `$sub_name` array:

```
$top_name = array( 'First Name', 'Second Name', 'Third Name', 'Fourth Name' );
$sub_name = array( 'Sub One', 'Sub Two' );
```

your two loops acts in this way:

```
1) main loop    > $i = 0 > executed
2)     2nd loop > $i = 0 > executed
3)     2nd loop > $i = 1 > executed
4)     2nd loop > $i = 2 > executed > undefined offset for $sub_name
5)     2nd loop > $i = 3 > executed > undefined offset for $sub_name
6) main loop    > $i = 4 > not executed
```

So, the deeper loop is executed also for non-existent `$sub_name` elements, whereas the main loop is executed only once.

In the second loop, you have to change incrementing variable name and condition variable:

```
for( $i=0; $i<sizeof( $top_name ); $i++ )
{
    for( $n=0; $n<sizeof( $sub_name ); $n++ )
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$sub_name[$n]."</td><td>".$sub_diff[$n]."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$top_name[$i]."</td><td>".$top_diff[$i]."</td>  <td>".$top_size[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```